# Avoid edit mistakes when having two duplicate files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have two folder references in my Xcode project tree and in each of them I have only one file that is the same everything else is different.

```
MyProject
  Folder1
    duplicatefile.js
  Folder2
    duplicatefile.js
```

I am looking for a way to avoid forgeting to update one of the files when changes have been made to the other(a.k.a keep them in sync).

I was thinking of deleting one of the files and making a copy from the other during the build steps in Xcode. Once copied however that file would become visible in the project structure as the folder containing it is linked as a reference which makes you see everything in it. Making the file invisible doesn't help as it is still seen in the project tree :/

The solution shouldn't require any set up by a developer that checks out the project from the SVN or when he commits.(a.k.a it should be magic).

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom scripts to run in Build Phase. Add a script to copy your `duplicatefile.js` from
 `Folder1` to `Folder2`.[image: Xcode]